# Why does my word counter produce a different output the first time I run it compared to the second time?

Tags: python

I am doing a basic project for practice. I call a simple wikipedia page, and then I write everything into a text file using Beautiful Soup. Then I count then number of times a word appears in that newly written text file

For some reason, the first time I run the code, I get a different number than the second time I run the code.

I believe that the first time I run the code, the "anime.txt" is different than the second time I run the code.

The problem must be with the way I gather all of my text data with Beautiful Soup.

Please help

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open("anime.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
f.write("")
f.close() 

my_url ="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anime"

uClient = urlopen(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")
p=page_soup.findAll("p")


f = open("anime.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8")

for i in p:

    f.write(i.text)
    f.write("\n\n")

data= open("anime.txt", encoding="utf-8").read()
anime_count = data.count("anime")
Anime_count = data.count("Anime")

print(anime_count,"\n")
print(Anime_count, "\n")

count= anime_count+Anime_count

print("The total number of times the word Anime appears within <p> in the wikipedia page is : ", count)
```

**first output:**

anime_count = 14

Anime_count = 97

count = 111

**second output:**

anime_count = 23

Anime_count = 139

count = 162

**EDIT:**

I edited my code base on the first 2 comments, and of course, it works now :P.
Does this look better in regards to Opening and Closing the file the proper way/number of times?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_url ="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anime"

uClient = urlopen(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")
p=page_soup.findAll("p")


f = open("anime.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")

for i in p:

    f.write(i.text)
    f.write("\n\n")

f.close()

data= open("anime.txt", encoding="utf-8").read()
anime_count = data.count("anime")
Anime_count = data.count("Anime")

print(anime_count,"\n")
print(Anime_count, "\n")

count= anime_count+Anime_count

print("The total number of times the word Anime appears within <p> in the wikipedia page is : ", count)
```

Comment: Why is the file opened and closed 3 times? Also, this code opens the file before it is closed. I can only assume that this leads to an undefined behavior.

Comment: In `open("anime.txt", "a")`, the "a" means "append". So if you run the script twice, duplicate elements of the same web page are added to your text file. Try using "w" (write") instead.

Comment: @EttoreRizza Note the `open(..., 'w')` and `f.write("")` at the very top. This truncates the file

Comment: After opening the file the second time, you don't close it before opening it the third time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not get confused about opening and closing files. Include all the writing/reading parts in [`with` statements](http://cmdlinetips.com/2016/01/opening-a-file-in-python-using-with-statement/).

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("anime.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:

    my_url ="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anime"

    uClient = urlopen(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")
    p=page_soup.findAll("p")


    for i in p:
        outfile.write(i.text)
        outfile.write("\n\n")

with open("anime.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as infile:
    data = infile.read()
    anime_count = data.count("anime")
    Anime_count = data.count("Anime")

    print(anime_count,"\n")
    print(Anime_count, "\n")

    count= anime_count+Anime_count

    print("The total number of times the word Anime appears within <p> in the wikipedia page is : ", count)s : ", count)
```